# Проблема с setTag

Tags: android, listview

Есть `ListView`, в каждом пункте которого в цикле выводятся `View` (кнопка). Мне нужно при клике на кнопку получить позицию item и позицию самой кнопки в item
Делаю так^

```
MusicPosit musicposit;
    for (int i =1;i<objects.get(position).getItems().size();i++){
                View item = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.internetitemtitle, null, false);
                TextView t = ((TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.internetitemtitleTextView1));
                TextView t1 = ((TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.internetitemtitleTextView2));


                musicposit.item = position;
                musicposit.music = i;
                t.setTag(musicposit);
                t.setText(objects.get(position).getItems().get(i).getTitle());
                t1.setText(objects.get(position).getItems().get(i).getArtist());
            t.setOnClickListener( new View . OnClickListener ()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        //int posiiiii=(Integer)v.getTag();
                        MusicPosit
                        musicposit = (MusicPosit)v.getTag();
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctx, "Позиция"+musicposit.item+" "+musicposit.music, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); toast.show();

                        }
                        });


                viewHolder.layot.addView(item);
            }
        }
static class MusicPosit{
int item;
int music;
}
```

position item выводит правильно, а вот позицию кнопки в item всегда последнюю (если цикл выполнялся 5 раз, то при клике на все 5  кнопок выводится 5)

Comment: Объект `musicposit` нужно создавать внутри цикла, для каждого элемента должен быть свой экземпляр.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло